# Axios html show value on div

Tags: html, json, reactjs, function, axios

Im trying to put a value that I get from axios on a div while I export that function

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function callServer() {
  axios.get(`http://localhost:${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_PORT}`, {
    params: {
      table: 'querotable',
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    const resp = response.data;
    console.log(resp);
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(resp)}</div>;
  });
}

export function SampleComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      {callServer()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

It shows nothing on div, only on console with the value that I want

Comment: @MihaiT I cant export a Async function with react, it returns: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Missing `return`

Your `callServer` function doesn't return anything.  It doesn't even return a `Promise`.  The statement `return <div>{JSON.stringify(resp)}</div>` is the `return` for the `.then` callback -- not for the function itself.

#### Use Component State

We could return a `Promise` that resolves to a `div` but that wouldn't be right.  In order to handle asynchronous data in `React` we want to store that data to state.

```
const [resp, setResp] = useState();
```

#### Side Effects Go in `useEffect`

We also need to make sure that the `axios.get` function is only called once instead of on every re-render of `SampleComponent`.  We can do that with a `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array.

```
export function SampleComponent() {
  const [resp, setResp] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_PORT}`, {
        params: {
          table: "querotable"
        }
      })
      .then((response) => setResp(response.data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(resp)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```